# AttributeError: 'Spreadsheet' object has no attribute 'range'

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

Hi stackoverflow community,
I am new to python. I want to edit a google spreadsheet using gspread. The following is the code I am using:

```
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

json_key = json.load(open('My Project-f3f034c4a23f.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('My Project-f3f034c4a23f.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

worksheet = gc.open('Roposo')

worksheet.update_acell('B1', 'Gspread!')
```

I am getting the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\spreadsheet.py", line 16, in 
    cell_list = worksheet.range('A1:C7')
AttributeError: 'Spreadsheet' object has no attribute 'range'

Please tell a suitable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable worksheet is the whole spreadsheet document not a worksheet. 
You should do something like

```
ss = gc.open('Roposo')
ws = ss.worksheet('myWorksheet') 
ws.update_acell('B1', 'Gspread !')
```

if a worksheet named `'myWorksheet'` already exists. Otherwise create a new worksheet with:

```
ss = gc.open('Roposo')
ws = ss.add_worksheet('title', 100, 20) #title, row, col
ws.update_acell('B1', 'Gspread !')
```

The API [documentation](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#main-interface) describes the two objects `Spreadsheet` and `Worksheet` more in detail.

Comment: Hi Jacques, your answer works when I create a new worksheet, but the following error comes up when I do use this code:
`ss = gc.open('Roposo')
ws = ss.get_worksheet('Aworksheet') 
ws.update_acell('B1', 'Gspread !')`
Error:
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\spreadsheet.py", line 15, in <module>
    ws = ss.get_worksheet('Aworksheet')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\gspread\models.py", line 154, in get_worksheet
    return self._sheet_list[index]
Type Error: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Oh sorry, the `get_worsheet` function takes an intger index as only parameter. Use `worksheet` instead to look up by title. Answer amended accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jacques